# Setting up dual monitors with VGA and HDMI out

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

My Computers has a built-in VGA Card. On the back of my Computer, it has a HDMI out and VGA out. Is there anyway i could setup dual monitors using these two ports. I want my screen to be extended into the other monitor I have. Both monitors have only VGA Ports.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to buy special converter, which will convert HDMI signal to VGA.